# Caliburn Micro Hello Screens

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a 3 part question about the "Hello Screens" Caliburn Micro example. (I'm using a WPF port of the project). This concerns the behavior of CustomerView.xaml which contains a "Save" and "Close" button pair. Willing to accept answers to just 1 and 2 as 3 probably becomes trivial at this point!

Whenever the AddressViewModel is activated by the DialogConductorViewModel the Save and Close buttons become disabled. This happens here in the EditAddress function of CustomerViewModel:

```
Dialogs.ShowDialog(new AddressViewModel());
```

1) How do the user controls of CustomerView know to become disabled here? My first thought was that CustomerViewModel (CMV) must've deactivated and maybe CM disables the the CustomerView UserControl for us as a result. However, if you override OnDeactivate in CMV the view model isn't being deactivated whenever it shows a dialog with the "ShowDialog" function.

2) From a WPF standpoint how do all the controls on CustomerView become disabled? If I put this code somewhere in CustomerView.xaml and run the project, the CustomerView UserControl remains enabled throughout:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"></TextBlock>
```

However, if I bind to IsEnabled on any control I place onto CustomerView.xaml that control's IsEnabled property is being set to false when a dialog is shown:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, 
                    ElementName=TryClose }"></TextBlock>
```

3) I would like to write a style datatrigger to alter other aspects of CustomerView's appearance whenever it's displaying a dialog. Ideally I would be binding to a property on CustomerViewModel but the best I can tell, this ViewModel doesn't inherently know whenever it's displaying a Dialog through the DialogManager unless there's something I've missed. Does CM give me a way to detect whenever this dialog is being displayed from the point of view of the CustVM?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: you don't show anywhere near enough code to spot the problem by looking at code

Comment: The reason for the sparseness was I assumed a familiarity with Hello Screens which is pretty well known by the Caliburn.Micro community. This project has dozens of files which small snippets of code so it's hard to post everything that might be relevant.

What additional code would you like to see?

Comment: fair enough - but samples on SO are expected to be complete. While that doesnt have to be the case all the time, in your scenario it would be tedious work. i for one usually prefer a git repository with the problem over everything else, since i've got every detail of the problem to look at then, by simply downloading it.

Comment: Download at the following link. In the samples folder, it's the Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens project:

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro